# Sharepoint premise, with office web app server, can andriod/ipad users edit docs?

Tags: office-web-apps, sharepoint-on-prem

I wasn't able to find this anywhere on the Microsoft site.
I know it is possible with Office 365 to edit a document on a android phone.

However what if a company uses SharePoint-premise 2013.

If i would install an office web app server. Would it allow for editing on Android/iphone devices as well these days (it's been 3 years ago the Microsoft wrote those clients have only viewing access, and i can't imagine that MS keeps ignoring Android as a major mobile device these days).

Did Office web app, got updates to allow these clients too editing their documents ?